When run karate,it run direct&unable to select specify karate runner.Resolved by enable "Prompt to specify Karate Runner before running karate tests"
When run feature file in karate, it run directly & is unable to select specify karate runner.
Usually, I am able to click on the "Run Test" icon, it will prompt a textbox for me to enter my karate runner file name, after inputting my karate runner file name and click on "Enter" button, the karate will be able to run.
Resolved by enable "Prompt to specify Karate Runner before running karate tests. Only applies when using Maven or Gradle."

In Visual Studio Code -> Karate Runner -> Click on the "Open Settings" icon
In Settings tab -> Navigate to Karate Runner › Karate Runner: Prompt To Specify
Tick this checkbox "Prompt to specify Karate Runner before running karate tests. Only applies when using Maven or Gradle." and done.

Hope the above steps help. Thanks.
